# Connecting to API, getting 409 back

Tags: python, api, request

I am completely new to APIs and I'm having a hard time connecting to Marvel API. Documentation says my connection link should be something like this:

> https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?nameStartsWith=Spider&apikey=XXXXX&hash=XXXXXX

hash is a md5 string containg from time stamp (or other string that would be changing every request, private key and public key)

I registered on their website and I have my keys, this is how I am trying to make a call to find Character who's name begins with "Spider"

Creating every request changing string:

`t ='{:%H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
t = t.replace(":", "")`

output: "213944"

hashing:

`m = hashlib.md5(t+private+public).hexdigest()`

pack I am trying to use:

```
pack = 'https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?nameStartsWith=Spider&apikey=<ACTUAL-API-KEY>&hash=' + m
```

Requesting printing response:

`response = requests.get(pack)
print(response)`

I keep getting back `Response[409]` and according to API documentation it means that I have wrong timestamp, public or private key. I spent hours already trying to find whats wrong and I need some help.

[This is a direct link to API documentation](https://developer.marvel.com/documentation/authorization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, you are missing the `ts` parameter. Add your `t` variable as the `ts` parameter.

`pack = 'https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?nameStartsWith=Spider&apikey=<ACTUAL-API-KEY>&hash=' + m + '&ts=' +t`

Also, the documentation states that `ts` to change on a request-by-request basis. Consider using `t=str(int(time.time()*1000))` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, got response 200!